# java http connection debug

Tags: java, http

I am trying to read text contents of a webpage ( based on [source](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=C61B87471BC8B564AD1B155967108179?Id=147) ), but seem to be unable to make the connection. What could be the issue?

**EDIT:** updated stack trace

I ran this is debug mode and see the following:

`JP_FetchWebPageHeader(Object).<init>()

Source not found`

I was able to single setp in spite of the above error. is this a error message an issue? 
I'm using eclipse on 64 bit windows and Java 1.7

The code is :

```
 // **** Fetch web page or header 
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class JP_FetchWebPageHeader { 
    /**
     * @param aArgs
     * <ul>
     * <li> aArgs[0] : an HTTP URL 
     * <li> aArgs[1] : (header | content) 
     * </ul>
     */
    public static void main(String...aArgs) throws MalformedURLException {
        String url = aArgs[0];
        String option = aArgs[1];
        JP_FetchWebPageHeader fetcher = new JP_FetchWebPageHeader(url);
        if (HEADER.equalsIgnoreCase(option)) { 
            log(fetcher.getPageHeader());
        }else if (CONTENT.equalsIgnoreCase(option)) { 
            log(fetcher.getPageContent());
        }else {
            log("Unknown option.");
        }

    }

    public JP_FetchWebPageHeader(URL aURL) { 
        if( ! HTTP.equals(aURL.getProtocol())) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URL isnt for HTTP protocol: " + aURL);
        }
        fURL = aURL;
    }

    public JP_FetchWebPageHeader(String aUrlName ) throws MalformedURLException { 
        this(new URL(aUrlName));
    }

    // Fetch the HTML content of the web page as simple text 
    public String getPageContent() { 
        String result = null;
        URLConnection connection = null;
        try { 
            connection = fURL.openConnection();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            scanner.useDelimiter(END_OF_INPUT);
            result = scanner.next();
        } catch (IOException ex ) { 
            log("Cannot open connection to " + fURL.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    //Fetch HTML headers as simple text
    public String getPageHeader() {
        return null;
    }

    //PRIVATE
    private URL fURL;

    private static final String HTTP = "http";
    private static final String HEADER = "header";
    private static final String CONTENT = "content";
    private static final String END_OF_INPUT  = "\\Z";
    private static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    private static void log(Object aObject){
        System.out.println(aObject);
    }
}
```

Arguments: `http://www.google.com   content`
Result :

`Cannot open connection to http://www.google.com
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
null
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at JP_FetchWebPageHeader.getPageContent(JP_FetchWebPageHeader.java:54)
    at JP_FetchWebPageHeader.main(JP_FetchWebPageHeader.java:30)`

Comment: The code is working, looks like a firewall / network problem.

Comment: I think it should work, but maybe you need a proxy which is configured in your browser but not in Java. Anyways, in your `catch(IoException ex)`, print out the exception including stack trace as well, this might give you a valuable hint.

Comment: Ok.. edited the question, I'm printing the stack trace as well now